# Dotnet web app in docker not displaying error stack

Tags: docker, .net-core

I am hosting a dotnet core application on linux inside a docker container.

Whenever there is an error in the app, it gives me blank page on the browser. Is there a way to see an error stack on the browser itself when there is an error on the page?

Answer (score 3):

Docker image run in non dev mode. Delete the below if statement and switch to app.UserDeveloperExceptionPage() instead of useExceptionHandler /Home/Error page.

Ensure that Startup.cs::Configure function has below code

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
```

You can also change the launchSettings.config and add the below:

```
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
```

The ErrorViewModel and Error.cshtml view are also present.

[image]

As long as your middleware is not tampered with you should be seeing an error message similar to this:

[image]